# Responsive Images in Bootstrap 5 with Given Layout

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-5, responsive-images

I am trying to create a web page that has one image per section. The image should be on either side of the text when viewed on a large screen, as displayed below:

[image: Desktop view]

However, I would like for each image to stack on top of each section once viewed on a smaller screen instead of continuing to be displayed side-by-side. Below is how it *should* look:

[image]

…but given the current implementation, this is how it looks right now:

[image]

**How should I be coding this page so the images are displayed appropriately on both desktop and on mobile?** I would like for the code to be able to replicate the first image on big screens, and the second image on smaller screens. However, if this is not a smart front end design and should be approached differently, I am open to different designs, especially if they are more generally accepted.

I am using Bootstrap 5 to achieve this layout. My code below is also using Javascript/React, but that should not be much of a factor.

Below is the code used in the first and third images:

```
class AboutSection extends Component {
render() {
    const startImage = "float-start me-4";
    const endImage = "float-end ms-4";
    var imageClass = "img-fluid my-4 rounded w-25 " + (IsOdd(this.props.index) ? startImage : endImage);

    return (
        <>
            <section class="p-4">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="d-sm-flex">
                        <div>
                            <img class={imageClass} src={Test} alt={this.props.imageAltText} />
                            <h2>{this.props.header}</h2>
                            <p class="lead my-3">{this.props.body}</p>
                            {this.props.subsection.map((item) => {
                                return (
                                    <AboutSubsection subheader={item.subheader} subbody={item.subbody} />
                                );
                            })}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </>
    );
}
```

Below is the code I changed to achieve the design of the second image:

```
class AboutSection extends Component {
render() {
    const startImage = "float-start me-4";
    const endImage = "float-end ms-4";
    var imageClass = "img-fluid my-4 rounded " + (IsOdd(this.props.index) ? startImage : endImage);

    return (
        <>
            <section class="p-4">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <img class={imageClass} src={Test} alt={this.props.imageAltText} />
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <h2>{this.props.header}</h2>
                            <p class="lead my-3">{this.props.body}</p>
                            {this.props.subsection.map((item) => {
                                return (
                                    <AboutSubsection subheader={item.subheader} subbody={item.subbody} />
                                );
                            })}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Bootstrap has rows and columns and your content should go inside a column. Your image is outside the column. Fix that first and read more about bootstrap layout. https://www.webnots.com/bootstrap-grid-layout-tutorial/ read any material on layouts.

Comment: I am aware of the rows/columns, but my thought was that I wouldn't be able to achieve the text overlapping the image layout that is seen on the first image. I did try to make the image its own column, but I noticed two things: one, the text did not flow into the image area once the image ends (leaving a bunch of ugly white space), and two, I was not able to dynamically left/right justify the image like I do in the code I posted.

Comment: Yes, the text won't flow below the image if you make md/lg of size 6. Only your mobile views will be perfect if you give xs=12 for your content and image.

Comment: What's the size of your image on desktop and what's on mobile? I can see the image is of size 500x500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is not write code for every kind of page, but always use the same one. To do this, you need to use responsive CSS styles, something like:

```
.img-right { float: right; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {

.img-right { float: none; width: 100%; }

}
```

It seems to me, that your task is NOT use bootstrap to format content. Bootstrap is designed to provide you with the basic design elements that are ready-made (design skeleton), and content is your area of responsibility. I think so...

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful and puts me on the right track for what I want to do! Can you elaborate more on what you say about not using Bootstrap to format content? I want to make sure that I am using it in the intended way and ensure that I can more quickly identify when to do my own CSS.

Comment: Actually, as I'm looking through some of the other options available in Bootstrap, I realized I am able to accomplish that snippet of code using the float-md-start/end class built into Bootstrap and accomplish the same thing without the custom CSS.

Comment: Of course using the bootstrap float classes, you can solve this problem. But it's worth looking at bootstrap example layout from the page https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/blog/

here I gave some explanations:

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/13103714?key=1c7045bcaef978b662e82bcf2f886e24 

if you need a more lively example of applying custom CSS classes to content - write

Comment: But more importantly, bootstrap float classes will not allow you to use one copy of the content for different display resolutions - and this is very useful especially if you are building a website for indexing and SEO (what I mentioned above)